# How can I export usedrange of values without exporting formulas in Visual Basic Excel

Tags: vba, excel, export-to-csv

I have tried multiple variations, and keep getting the same result.  The most recent iteration is this:

```
Sub CopyToCSV()

' Copy and Paste Active Sheet
ActiveSheet.Copy
With ActiveSheet.UsedRange
    .Value = .Value
End With

 'The new workbook becomes Activeworkbook:
With ActiveWorkbook


      'Saves the new workbook to given folder / filename:
     .SaveAs Filename:= _
     "C:\upload\19meat-kl.csv", _
     FileFormat:=xlCSV, _
     CreateBackup:=False
      'Closes the file
     .Close False
  End With
End Sub
```

My output keeps looking like this:

```
Store,Department,Date,Category,Item Count,Retail Price,Dollars,Reduced Retail,Total Loss,Reason for loss
18,90,2017-04-04,Meat,2,3,6,1,4,Out of Date
18,90,2017-04-04,Pork,2,1.5,3,0.99,1.02,Other
,,,,,,,,,
,,,,,,,,,
,,,,,,,,,
,,,,,,,,,
,,,,,,,,,
```

The reason is that my Excel file contains some formulas like this:

```
=IF(D5>0,TODAY(),"")
```

This auto fills some of the cells if they enter anything into certain cells. This causes Excel to think that the cells are "used" and includes them.  I attempted several variations of Worksheet.usedrange.values and I either get the same output or I get a debug prompt due to bad code.  How can I remove the commas from the output?

Comment: no need for copy, just saveas CSV see if that helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**edited** to include the whole code

just Clear the *nearly-blank* cells

```
Sub CopyToCSV()
    ' Copy and Paste Active Sheet
    ActiveSheet.Copy
    With ActiveSheet.UsedRange
        .Value = .Value
        .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Delete
    End With

    'The new workbook becomes Activeworkbook:
    With ActiveWorkbook
        'Saves the new workbook to given folder / filename:
        .SaveAs Filename:="C:\upload\19meat-kl.csv", FileFormat:=xlCSV, CreateBackup:=False
        'Closes the file and discard changes (no needed any more)
        .Close False
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: @AaronMartin, did you get through it?

Comment: I inserted that just after With ActiveWorkBook and am still getting the commas for the rows containing formulas.  I removed the With ActiveWorkBook and the associated End With and it still errored out.  I moved the End With down below the .SaveAs phrase and just before the End Sub line and it still crashes but it generates the file, just doesn't save it.  I can see that the Excel file generated has the rows removed I just can't get it to export to csv now...  Any suggestions?

Comment: you have to insert it _before_  `With ActiveWorkBook`, i.e. replace your `With ActiveSheet.UsedRange ... End With` block

Comment: It looks like it would work, the part when it asks if you want to overwrite the file even the formatting is removed and I only see two lines below the header, but once you overwrite the file (and I deleted the file to make sure the file was actually being written to) it still has the rows with commas.

Comment: I can't follow you: I tested the code before posting it and it worked. be sure you are opening the same file in the same folder produced by the code

Comment: This is the only VB code I have in the file:

Sub CopyToCSV()

' Copy and Paste Active Sheet
ActiveSheet.Copy
Dim i As Integer
  With Sheets(1).Columns("A").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
    i = .Cells(.Cells.Count).Row
  End With

 'The new workbook becomes Activeworkbook:
With ActiveWorkbook


      'Saves the new workbook to given folder / filename:
     .SaveAs Filename:= _
     "C:\upload\19meat-kl.csv", _
     FileFormat:=xlCSV, _
     CreateBackup:=False
      'Closes the file
     .Close False
  End With
End Sub

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139998/discussion-between-aaron-martin-and-user3598756).

Comment: you were mixing up two codes (mine and Amorpheuses's one) . see edited code

Comment: I copied the edited code and the same output.  Maybe the issue is that it is saving the original file rather than the new workbook?  At the prompt to save the file I cancel then check within the cells of the newly created workbook and there are no formulas below the two rows anymore so the new file looks good, I think it is still exporting the original file that's the only way I can see that it could export empty rows any more.

Comment: at the prompt you must click "YES"!!

Comment: Yes I know, I did that I only clicked no so that I could check out the Book1 file that gets generated for the output so I could make sure the newly generated file did not still include the formulas.  That was a troubleshooting step I took, not normal operation.  When I click yes it generates the same output.  Can I send you the original file?  Perhaps something will jump out at you that I am omitting.

Comment: I wouldn't open any excel file from internet. You can link an image.

Comment: Fair enough.

Here is file, selected cell has formula (all dark shaded contain formulas)
[IMG]http://i63.tinypic.com/2ng8qvo.jpg[/IMG]

Here is the Visual Basic on the Module 
[IMG]http://i65.tinypic.com/4to5za.jpg[/IMG]

Here is what it looks like when it processes the file
[IMG]http://i67.tinypic.com/358axzo.jpg[/IMG]

Comment: try edited answer. if it solves your question then please mark answer as accepted. thank you!

Comment: Fantastic!  Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of copying and pasting the entire used range, you can copy from your starting row to the last row that doesn't have a formula in it.  That last row can be found by using this:

```
  Dim i As Integer
  With Sheets(1).Columns("A").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
    i = .Cells(.Cells.Count).row
  End With
```